# Why does a method with the same name as the class not need a return type?

Tags: java

Why is this legal?:

```
public class TwoFrames extends JFrame {
    public TwoFrames() {
        return;
    };
}
```

And this isn't (NetBeans IDE saying **invalid method declaration; return type required**)?:

```
public class TwoFrames extends JFrame {
    public firstFrame() {
        return;
    };
}
```

Comment: Clear now.  I'll get this language down sooner than later with the great input of people like yourselves.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a constructor. It is called once the object is initialized. For example:

`TwoFrames twoFrames = new TwoFrames();`

Unlike regular methods constructors does not return any value. Why should it?

Also, the constructor has to have the **same name** as the class.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class TwoFrames extends JFrame {
    public TwoFrames() {
        return;
    };
}
```

This is actually a [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Constructor declarations look like methods, but they don't have return types. They are not, strictly speaking, methods, although you may hear "constructor method" from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

A method with the same name as the class is a constructor, which is called when an object of the class is created.

A method that has a different name must have a return type, even if it's void.

Answer (score 0):

It has a return type, but no name. This is because it returns and instance of the class. Things enclosed in this method are called when you use the `new` keyword.